How to plot a mix of sf POLYGONS/MULTIPOLYGONS with latest {ggplot2} version
With the latest versions of {sf} and {ggplot2}, unionized geoms cannot be plotted anymore if geometry contains both POLYGONs.
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# latest sf and ggplot2 versions
packageVersion("sf")
#> [1] '1.0.16'
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.1'

# prep data
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source 
#>   `/mnt/rstudio_data/server-pro/c804893/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/sf/shape/nc.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27

# convert to tata.table for easier data wrangling
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(nc)

# aggregate Polygons
dt_agg <- dt[, .(GEOMETRY = sf::st_union(geometry)),
             by = .(SID74)]

# Mix of Multipolygons and Polygons
st_geometry_type(dt_agg$GEOMETRY)
#>  [1] MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON
#>  [6] MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON
#> [11] MULTIPOLYGON POLYGON      MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON MULTIPOLYGON
#> [16] MULTIPOLYGON POLYGON      MULTIPOLYGON POLYGON      POLYGON     
#> [21] MULTIPOLYGON POLYGON      POLYGON     
#> 18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE

# plotting does not work
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_sf(data = dt_agg,
                   mapping = ggplot2::aes(geometry = GEOMETRY)) 
#> Error in `ggplot2::geom_sf()`:
#> ! Problem while converting geom to grob.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Not a matrix.

# Multipolygons work
# ggplot2::ggplot() +
#   ggplot2::geom_sf(data = dt_agg[1:10],
#                    mapping = ggplot2::aes(geometry = GEOMETRY)) 

# Polygons do not work
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_sf(data = dt_agg[12],
                   mapping = ggplot2::aes(geometry = GEOMETRY))
#> Error in `ggplot2::geom_sf()`:
#> ! Problem while converting geom to grob.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Not a matrix.

Created on 2024-08-12 with reprex v2.1.1


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language en_US:en
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Zurich
#>  date     2024-08-12
#>  pandoc   2.19.2 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)


This seems to be an incompatibility with {data.table} not {ggplot2}.
You can instead leave the data as a (spatial) data.frame and use:
library(dplyr)

nc |>
   summarise(GEOMETRY = st_union(geometry), .by = SID74) ## |>
   ## etc.

